# BMW X3 Jumps to Parking mode

Tags: automatic-transmission, bmw

I drive a 2012 BMW X3 F25 (2.0d) automatic.
Very frequently, when I come to a halt,
the shifter jumps to parking mode.
If I disable the Start/Stop system, the problem seems
to disappear.
I got many ideas from various service centers,
ranging from replacing a solenoid to the entire 
Transmission.
Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: How many miles have you driven on this car until now? When does the warranty expire? At what point did you notice this problem?

Comment: The computer would not just decide to throw you in park all on its own. If I was a betting man, there must be some erroneous input that is causing the computer to put you in park. Unfortunately, the had part is going to be finding what the strategy the computer has for park operation and the following up all the components in the system checking their operation during the event. This usually involves back probing the component, running wires into the cab, connecting them to a Digital Storage Oscilloscope and then driving around. When the car jumps into park check the DSO for events.

Comment: I say rent an obd2 scanner and check for codes

Comment: you are not alone http://www.bimmerfest.com/forums/showthread.php?t=760398

Comment: My 2013 is at the dealership now for the same issue. They just called and said it’s because I need a new battery.$400+
Let’s see if that fixes it. I’ll check back after I drive it a bit.